# how to create nodejs xmpp server and android xmpp client

Tags: java, android, node.js

I want to add chat module to android app. Firstly I want to use XMPP using Nodejs. How nodejs xmpp server works with android client.

Can nodejs xmpp server can communicate with android app? if yes than, how can i create simple nodejs xmpp server and simple android app that both can communicate.

If you have any other solution please let me know.

I am tried socket.io but i dont want to use that. It is not worked stable on android client side. Some messages send some not send. I am used few solutions for solve this problem (ping pong, heartbeath, change java client libraries for socket io, ...). But nothing changed.

My aim is to create stable fast chat module to android and ios application using with nodejs server.

Please guide me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking other solutions like ConnectyCube, Firebase, Layer, etc.?

They provide a ready backend and all you need to care about is configuring your client-side app.

Some of them even have ready Android client-side libraries which can be integrated in your app and speed up the development.